# When to write out in Views or Models in Django

Tags: python, django

I have been in the process of learning how to use Django from scratch, and while I feel I have learned a lot from countless tutorials, once I stop and try to start my own project, I'm at a stage where I just don't really know how to go about it without a guide, and I figured that it may be because syntax and python logic aside, I have not really understood philosophically how to think about things.

So my question here is, when should any logic belong in a Django Model? My understanding is that Models are the instructions for how database tables should be created, and Views are how information in the models should be pulled and handled when communicating to the end-user, via the Template.

But then I see an example in the Official Tutorial such as:

```
polls/models.py
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Why would something like def was_published_recently(self) belong in a Model? The data of the question (pub_date) is all that is necessary in terms of having a minimal and concise database, so why wouldn't a function like that belong in a view, where for instance, the 5 most recent Questions can be posted on the homepage, and is just handled as a context instead of a method?

All input is appreciated, and if you have any suggestions at certain tutorials/exercises that could maybe help me overcome this wall I've hit from your own personal experiences, I would be very interested in hearing about that as well.

Cheers!

Comment: rule of the thumb: a business logic doesnt belong to View. Also if you ask what does it say ("was it published recently?"), do you feel it's more related to the Question (ie. model), or to the view?

Comment: have you done the Entire official django tutorial? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/, if still having issues, there are a lot of others; if you like books, try "Two Scoops of django"

Comment: If you prefer the pragmatic answer, the code belongs in a view if it's *only* relevant to the view and in the model if it's potentially something you might use in more than one context. Methods & properties that indicate status, category, type, scope, etc. are generally the kinds of things that get reused, therefore making them a part of the model increases their value, quality and effort/return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a Django view as a verb and a Django model as a noun.  The method on a Django model is an adjective and specifically relates to an instance of the model (though some methods can be used to tell Django things about the class itself).

As an analogy, consider a model `Car` with an attribute `year` that tells us the year in which an individual member of `Car` was built.  In some states, for inspection purposes, a "new" car is any car that is less than two or three years old.  A "new" car may cost less to inspect, since you don't need to do emissions tests.

Here, "new" is an adjective that describes an instance of the `Car` class.  If we wanted to have a function `is_new` that tells us whether the car can be considered "new" or not, we would attach that to the model.  We could then do `car = Car(<car info here>)` and then do `car.is_new()` to find out if we can save on our inspections.

Answer (score 3):

Your misunderstanding is here:

> Models are the instructions for how database tables should be created

That is *one* part of a model, certainly, but far from the only part. Models are the fundamental data objects of your application, and the whole point of doing object-orientated programming - rather than querying the database directly and passing around data rows - is that these objects are rich. They contain methods that deal with the data they contain; `was_published_recently` is a great example of the kind of thing  a model method should do.